# How do I find unique, non-English characters in a SQL script that has a lot of tables, scripts, etc. related to it?

Tags: python, sql

I am getting a UnicodeDecodeError in my Python script and I know that the unique character is not in Latin (or English), and I know what row it is in (there are thousands of columns).  How do I go through my SQL code to find this unique character/these unique characters?

Comment: What SQL code do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a binary search. Break the files (or the scripts, or whatever) in half, and process both files. One will (should) fail, and the other shouldn't. If they both have errors, doesn't matter, just pick one.

Continue splitting the broken files until you've narrowed it down to the something more manageable that you can probe in to, even down to the actual line that's failing.